# empty map when run code in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have a problem with the `show map`, But why show `empty map` ?! like in images

[image: sample]

I'll introduce you my code 
I put key in file `release/res/values/google_map_api.xml` and also put in `debug/res/values/google_map_api.xml`

```
<resources>
    <string name="google_maps_key" translatable="false" templateMergeStrategy="preserve">
        AIzaSyDci-------------hSik
    </string>
</resources>
```

also I put my key in `androidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDci-------------hSik" />
```

and the code of `MapActivity.java`

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Note: Use Mobile `Galaxy Note` not `emulator` of android studio.

Comment: Can you add logcat and `activity_maps` layout file ?

Comment: Try to use `MagFragment` instead of `SupportMapFragment`

Comment: I did not understand how to add logcat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the permission part under manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<permission
        android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<permission
          android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

Comment: did not change the result when add permission

Comment: Did you enable Google Maps Android API from Google API Console?

Comment: The key is the sum of your SHA; package name, right?

Answer (score 0):

Add This in android manifest

```
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```